# Self-referencing array in typescript class

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to create a class hierarchy with a recursive array that references it self, but also correctly assigns type to subclasses. 
I think I'm close, but I'm getting an inexplicable `TS2351` error

```
export interface ContentNodeJSON {
  id: string
  parentId?: string
  children: ContentNodeJSON[]
}

export class ContentNode {
  id: string
  parentId?: string
  children: this[]

  constructor(model: ContentNodeJSON) {
    this.id = model.id;
    this.parentId = model.parentId;
    this.children = model.children.map(child => new this(child));
  }
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'ContentNode' has no construct signatures.  TS2351
    20 |     this.parentId = model.parentId;
  > 21 |     this.children = model.children.map(child => new this(child));
       |                                                     ^
    22 |   }
```

Is it just impossible to call a constructor from itself? Is there some other pattern I should be using to accomplish this goal?

**Edit:**

To clarify what I mean by "correctly assigns type to subclasses", if I define a subclass as:

```
class Page extends ContentNode {}
```

Then `Page.children` needs to be of type `Page`, not `ContentNode`.

Comment: You have a typo as well: `id: string (`

Comment: `children: this[]` should be `children: ContentNode[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call a constructor, so it should be `this.constructor` instead of just `this`. However, Typescript doesn't seem to like that, since `this.constructor` is of type `Function` which isn't a constructor signature; I don't know why Typescript doesn't know that a constructor is a constructor, but we can make a type assertion to say that *we* know it is:

```js
    const _constructor = this.constructor as new (...args: any[]) => this;
    this.children = model.children.map(child => new _constructor(child));
```

Note that there's something a bit fishy about `children: this[]`, since if `obj` has the type `ContentNode` then you can write `obj.children.push(new ContentNode(...))` and it will type-check even though `obj` could be a `Page` instance at runtime. This issue could be avoided by declaring it as `readonly children: ReadonlyArray<this>`.

You're also constraining subclasses to have a constructor taking a single parameter of type `ContentNodeJSON`, but beware that this constraint won't be checked at compile-time.

Comment: I’m new to typescript, so this pattern may not be idiomatic. It’s very common in Swift where you will type a collection as `[Self]` and subclasses will all automatically infer the correct type at runtime. I can see how it may be less valuable when all our type safety disappears at runtime.

Comment: I've edited to mention that you can declare `readonly children: ReadonlyArray<this>` as a solution to that problem. That doesn't make the array actually immutable, but the compiler will check that you aren't mutating it.

Answer (score 0):

[This works](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQhWBQDkIATYAKQGUB5UuAbwFgAoOLxCgLjgDOMKMgDmAbg7c4YTFBIwAkhQD8-ISKQSp3bAAsEAGwryk-QsTKUaDUgG0AupPYBfDh1CRYcbIcwCBAiJUKyoWHS4EPkFhMWdpWVMlVXVYrXjdA2NTc2CFcipHZwifIg0AV2wYaAAKAFtrQ1zLGAKbRgBKcM5pbhgDAQA6KLgAXjgGqkNhigzeuH6EIcSFZTGJxsGVlGU53sWh-SMTEnXJ4Gmj7JJBuswwGquKMYA+OCRgAHcglrbHrIoHQ6ezcriAA)

```
export interface ContentNodeJSON {
    id: string;
    parentId?: string;
    children: ContentNodeJSON[];
}

export class ContentNode {
    id: string;
    parentId?: string;
    children: ContentNode[];

    constructor(model: ContentNodeJSON) {
        this.id = model.id;
        this.parentId = model.parentId;
        this.children = model.children.map(child => new ContentNode(child));
    }
}
```

You can use `new ContentNode` inside `ContentNode.constructor` because under the hood it will compile into a function (or more precisely, something one could view as a function, but I digress), so it's basically recursion, and JS allows that.

To answer your edit (that's borderline a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), but anyway), you could use generic types like this:

```
export class ContentNode<T> {
    id: string;
    parentId?: string;
    children: ContentNode<T>[];

    constructor(model: ContentNodeJSON) {
        this.id = model.id;
        this.parentId = model.parentId;
        this.children = model.children.map(child => new ContentNode(child));
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment in the edit, making children a `ContentNode` won't work.

Comment: I don't think it's a chameleon question; I understood this requirement from the original wording and the use of the polymorphic `this` type which I assumed was intentional.